# Query on statistics shown on pg_stat_progress_vacuum

Tags: postgresql, psql, vacuum

I'm trying to understand what the below parameters mean: `max_dead_tuples` / `num_dead_tuples` on the `pg_stat_progress_vacuum` view.

From the Postgres documentation:

> `max_dead_tuples` `bigint`    Number of dead tuples that we can store before needing to perform an index vacuum cycle, based on `maintenance_work_mem`.
>
> `num_dead_tuples` `bigint`    Number of dead tuples collected since the last index vacuum cycle.

Does this mean this value is changed per the `maintenance_work_mem` allocations? I have tried setting different values to this parameter and the number on `max_dead_tuples` increased to 178956970 and does not move further. Even if I reduce the `maintenance_work_mem` this counter stays the same. Why is that so? What does these two parameter indicate?

Edit:

Noticed that when I reset the stats using select `pg_stat_reset()`; after changing `maintenance_work_mem`, I see different values in `max_dead_tuples`. But I don't understand why the values are inconsistent?

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VACUUM` proceeds like this:

1. it scans the table until it has found as many dead tuples as fit into `autovacuum_work_mem` (which defaults to `maintenance_work_mem`). `max_dead_tuples` is PostgreSQL's estimate how many tuples will fit in `autovacuum_work_mem`.
2. It scans all indexes and removes entries pointing to those dead tuples.

These two steps are repeated until the whole table is processed. `num_dead_tuples` are the number of dead tuples already found in the current iteration.

As far as I know, changing `maintenance_work_mem` doesn't influence an already running `VACUUM`, but I may be wrong.